# Is Saudi Arabia hosting ~2.5 million Syrian refugees?

Tags: immigration, saudi-arabia, syria, refugees

After being criticized for not doing enough to help refugees, Saudi Arabia's Ministry of Foreign Affairs [declared](https://www.facebook.com/ksamofa/photos/a.501311693212397.121894.187734237903479/1132934476716779/) that they have been helping after all. Among others, it specifically claims that it has taken more than 2.5 million Syrians.

> The Kingdom has received around 2.5 million Syrians since the
>   beginning of the conflict. In order to ensure their dignity and
>   safety, the Kingdom adopted a policy that does not treat them as
>   refugees or place them in refugee camps. They have been given the
>   freedom to move about the country and those who wish to remain in
>   Saudi Arabia (some hundreds of thousands) have been given legal
>   residency status like the remaining residents. ‌ Their residency comes
>   with the rights to receive free medical care, to join the labor market
>   and to attend schools and universities. This was contained in a royal
>   decree in 2012 that instructed public schools to accept Syrian
>   students. According to government statistics, the public school system
>   has accepted more than 100,000 Syrian students.

This is surprising, not because I doubt the Saudis' generosity, but because the sheer number. 2.5 million would surpass what any other country hosts. [This data sheet](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2015/09/syrias-refugee-crisis-in-numbers/) shows Turkey host 1.9 million, and is thought to be the country with the most Syrian refugees. Note that Turkey is closer to Syria and more populous than Saudi Arabia ( you could even say richer if you count total GDP). The data sheet also shows that in total, all the (non-Saudi) countries are thought to host about 4 million, so 2.5 million is more than half that.

Are there other data or information that corroborate or give serious doubt to this very specific claim?

Comment: Isn't this a duplication of [this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30007/is-saudi-arabia-funding-200-mosques-but-not-accepting-any-refugees)?

Comment: Not sure what the rules for duplication is in this site. I did take a look at it briefly, I think the main difference is here I am referring to a more recent and a more specific claim by the Saudis, not just a claim by third party.

Comment: My answer doesn't tackle this claim. Is there a way to verify their claim? I doubt.

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30031/have-the-rich-arab-states-accepted-almost-no-syrian-refugees may be a better duplicate target.

Comment: The other claim was found to have a shaky source--that does nothing about addressing this claim.  Thus this is not a duplicate even though both questions are about the same basic subject matter.

Comment: The other question is quite different, certainly not a duplicate.